# Create target directory outside project directory with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

The structure of my project is:

```
└───current-working-dir
    ├───my-project
        ├───src
```

When I run `sbt compile` in current-working-dir where .sbt file looks like:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("my-project"))
  .settings(
    name := "my-project",
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )
```

then it generates target in the project directory:

```
└───current-working-dir
    ├───my-project
        ├───src
        ├───target
```

Is it possible to make sbt to create target outside the project directory? For instance:

```
└───current-working-dir
    ├───my-project
        ├───src
    ├───target
```

or

```
└───current-working-dir
    ├───my-project
        ├───src
    ├───my-project-compilation
        ├───target
```

Answer (score 2):

[`target`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L114) setting controls where files are generated. Here is an example how to change it

```
target := baseDirectory.value / "my-project-compilation" / "target"
```

Comment: not user where to place it... When I have put it into `.settings(...)` then it nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I guess correct is

```
lazy val root = (project in file("my-project"))
  .settings(
    name := "my-project",
    settings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    target := baseDirectory.value / ".." / "my-project-compilation" / "target"
  )
```

You can check that if you place file as `current-working-dir/my-project/src/main/scala/App.scala` then compiled class appears as `current-working-dir/my-project-compilation/target/scala-2.13/classes/App.class`.